# Angular ng serve Error in Debug Failure

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material, node-modules

I just got this debug failure randomly. My app was OK yesterday. I just wanted to continue my job when this happened.

[startingfrom terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMUiX.png) ,[starting from webstorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG2Vj.png)

I don't have any syntax error. I did not changed anything in my code from my last correct build. This error just randomly appeared.
I tried to remove my node_modules folder and run npm install -> error still happens when I'm doing ng serve.
(Path to the project not contains a folder whose name starts with an exclamation mark...)

Comment: Did you get an update in Typescript maybe? Here is someone who had a similar issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8529

Comment: Can you provide the content of your package.json please?

Comment: Sure: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11RHKNGS-X3Nixr5sWMZUB4687qg5dimX

Comment: @Matheno thanks for the tip but i dont have any error like this one you recommended

Comment: I just used ng build --aot --prod, hope i can see much more
https://ibb.co/gy2i66

Comment: did you try to fix before the angular CLI warning which is in your screenshot? Try to upgrade the CLI in your local project.

Comment: I had no problem so far with this warning. Upgrading thinks is very dangerous in angular :/ as i experienced